# remaining spaces left for items SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help
Q: get total remaining spaces for items preferably in 1 query

```
Grops, items
Group can contain only MaxAllowed items

Groups table
(ID, MAXAllowerdItems)

Items
(ID, Group_ID, Name)
```

This is not the correct query but a starting point

```
select SUM(g.MaxAllowedItems - count(*)),  
from FROM items i, Groups g
where g.ID=i.Group_ID
GROUP BY i.Group_ID
HAVING g.MaxAllowedItems > count( * )
```

Comment: Don't forget to remove one of the `FROM`s from the query and to remove the comma after `select SUM(g.MaxAllowedItems - count(*)),`...

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this:

```
SELECT
  groups.ID,
  MAX(MAXAllowerdItems) - COUNT(items.Group_ID) as remaining_spaces
FROM
  groups LEFT JOIN items
  ON groups.ID = items.Group_ID
GROUP BY
  groups.ID
HAVING
  remaining_spaces > 0
```

`MAX(MAXAllowerdItems)` will always have the same value of MAXAllowerdItems, and `COUNT(items.Group_ID)` will be the number of used rows for that group ID.

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9bba9/2).

Comment: I think you'll still want the `GROUP BY` clause in there in order for the `MAX` and/or `COUNT` aggregation to work... No?

Comment: @BroadCastic you're welcome :) pls don't forget to accept the answer if you find it useful, and if you wish... thanks! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work